# Request not waiting PHP long process, returning 503 Service unavailable

Tags: php, apache, http

I wanted to test max_execution_time setting by using ini_set function from PHP. So I setup a simple test that create an infinite loop to make sure it will timeout.

Here is my code

```
Test.php
<?php         
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   echo "Hello World";
   //for(;;); Commented, see history
   sleep(100);

?>
```

This code is work nicely on my Windows machine running on top XAMPP. After 5 minutes, it will show Hello World and the fatal error exceeding time out.

Then I move my code to my VPS running ubuntu and Apache. Then I open the web page from browser. But, after only 1 minute, my browser shows

```
Error Code: 503 Service Unavailable
Network Error 
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
```

It doesn't even wait for 5 minutes. And it consistently get error after 1 minute. But in my error log, Apache write the fatal error exceeding time after 5 minutes.

So, in my opinion, the request get cancelled before the PHP script actually done.

I use default setting on apache2.conf with additional my virtual host

```
apache2.conf (additional only)
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

mysite.virtualhost.conf

<VirtualHost virtualhost.mysite.com:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    ServerName virtualhost.mysite.com
    ServerAlias virtualhost.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Php.ini file

```
Php.ini
safe_mode = off
max_execution_time = 1200
```

So, what config do I miss here? I think that there is something wrong in my apache config but I don't know which part.

**UPDATE**

After looking at process running, apache process that running the infinite loop is consuming 99% of CPU. Why is this happening? Using strace to look at the process returning this

```
write(10, "36.72.135.58 - - [22/Jul/2016:03:15:35 +0700] \"GET /test11.php HTTP/1.1\" 500 211 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\"\n", 198) = 198
times({tms_utime=29996, tms_stime=4, tms_cutime=0, tms_cstime=0}) = 4967918020
gettimeofday({1469132442, 496002}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1469132442, 496046}, NULL) = 0
shutdown(17, SHUT_WR)                   = 0
poll([{fd=17, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 1 ([{fd=17, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
read(17, "", 512)                       = 0
close(17)                               = 0
read(5, 0x7fff82f5cf67, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
gettimeofday({1469132442, 496411}, NULL) = 0
accept4(4,  <detached ...>
```

Comment: what php config? not all config allow ini settings to be overwritten via ini_set

Comment: i've added php safe_mode off, and it actually overwrite php.ini max_execution_time, because it is even longer which is 1200. Will update my question with php.ini config

Comment: The `503` response code makes it seem *really* likely that there may be some sort of proxy or other gateway between your VPS and you that is configured with a lower timeout.  The 503 response is coming from a server which would be different than your browser aborting the request (there would be not http response) because it took too long or something in the middle just bombing out and closing the connection.  Do you know more about your hosting platform?  Do they offer any sort of geographic load balancing or DDOS protection? Services like these might mean something else is in play.

Comment: If PHP is running as a CGI or Apache module?  Are you sure it's Apache writing the fatal error after 5 minutes and not something like php-fpm writing to it's own log?

Comment: PHP is running as Apache module. I'm using digital ocean as VPS provider. Any idea what kind of proxy could be there? There is also an instance of apache tomcat also running of that machine.

Comment: After looking at process running, apache process that running the infinite loop is consuming 99% of CPU. Why is this happening? question updated with strace result

Comment: Update: changing my code to use sleep(100) instead of infinite loop. CPU doesn't get 100% again, but the network error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i solved increasing first_byte_timeout of varnish at
/etc/varnish/default.vcl default was 60 change that according to your needs.